# Is `goal symbol` the same thing as `start symbol` in context-free-grammar

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, compiler-construction

[Context free grammar](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compiler_design/compiler_design_syntax_analysis.htm) define the four constituent parts:

> - A set of non-terminals (V)...
> - A set of tokens, known as terminal symbols (Σ)...
> - A set of productions (P)...
> - One of the non-terminals is designated as **the start symbol** (S); from
>     where the production begins.

[The EcmaScript specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-context-free-grammars) doesn't mention **start symbol**, instead it mentions a **goal symbol**:

> **Starting from a sentence** consisting of a single distinguished
>   nonterminal, called the **goal symbol**, a given context-free grammar
>   specifies a language, namely, the (perhaps infinite) set of possible
>   sequences of terminal symbols that can result from repeatedly
>   replacing any nonterminal in the sequence with a right-hand side of a
>   production for which the nonterminal is the left-hand side.

From this definition I can probably conclude **that goal symbol is actually just another name for a start symbol**, but the `goal symbol` name is used because there are different start symbols "categories":

> There are several situations where the identification of lexical input
>   elements is sensitive to the syntactic grammar context that is
>   consuming the input elements. This requires multiple goal symbols for
>   the lexical grammar.

So is goal symbol is another name for start symbol in the context of CFG?

Comment: what is the reason for a close vote?

Comment: probably because its exceeding the knowledge of the common SO answerer? ;)

Comment: @Jonasw, yeah, I'm still hoping there are people who understand the EcmaScript on that level

Comment: Thanks, Max (@AngularInDepth.com), I was just wondering the same thing. In case you are still diving into the spec, I have posted a few related questions, including this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49604170/ecmascript-2017-why-does-escapesequence-include-nonescapecharacter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Yes

What you have cited is just one definition of CFG - there are others. For example from [here](https://classes.engineering.wustl.edu/cse425s/resources/bnf/):

> A grammar is the 4-tuple:
>
> 1. A set of **terminal symbols** (i.e. the valid "words" of the language).
> 2. A set of **non-terminal symbols** (i.e. the "parts-of-speech" of the language).
> 3. A set of rules known as **productions** which can transform each non-terminal into a sequence of terminals.
> 4. A ***start symbol*** or **goal symbol**, the non-terminal to generate (e.g., in English: the "sentence").

From my cursory web search, it seems that the term "goal symbol" is more often used when discussing parsers. I guess it's because there are bottom-up parsers such as [LR-parsers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR_parser) where the algorithm does not *start* with the goal symbol.

Btw, the particular paragraph from the ECMAScript spec appears to be literally copied from the [Java Language Specification](http://titanium.cs.berkeley.edu/doc/java-langspec-1.0/2.doc.html) - so you can blame anything on them :-)

Comment: thanks for the confirmation! _appears to be literally copied from the Java Language Specification_ - that's what I noticed as well. I started to look at Java spec as @Pointy suggested and noticed full paragraphs similar word in word.